# Error trying to deploy a function on firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

Hello I am getting an error trying to deploy a function on firebase and it is bothering me because it worked in the past and now that I wanted to deploy the same code it is giving me the error above.

Can someone have a look because I checked the documentation thinking that something might change and the names of the attributes or something are not the same but the function seems 100% sound based on the documentation.

Kind regards and kudos to everyone.

Much respect if someone manages to give me a hint. I will add the log files also.

Code :

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const axios = require("axios");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp();
const database = admin.firestore();
const page = 1;
const fiat = "RON";
const tradeType = "BUY";
const asset = "USDT";
const payTypes = ["ING"];
let finalData = [];
let tempDataBeforeProccessing = [];

const baseObj = {
  page,
  rows: 20,
  publisherType: null,
  asset,
  tradeType,
  fiat,
  payTypes,
};

const stringData = JSON.stringify(baseObj);

const getTheData = async function() {
  tempDataBeforeProccessing=[];
  await axios.post("https://p2p.binance.com/bapi/c2c/v2/friendly/c2c/adv/search", baseObj, {
    hostname: "p2p.binance.com",
    port: 443,
    path: "/bapi/c2c/v2/friendly/c2c/adv/search",
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Content-Length": stringData.length,
    },
  }).then((res)=>{
    tempDataBeforeProccessing=res.data.data;
  });
};


const processData = function() {
  finalData=[];
  let obj = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < tempDataBeforeProccessing.length; i++) {
    let payTypesz = "";
    for (let y = 0; y <
    tempDataBeforeProccessing[i]["adv"]["tradeMethods"].length; y++) {
      payTypesz +=
      tempDataBeforeProccessing[i]["adv"]["tradeMethods"][y]["identifier"];
      if (y <
      tempDataBeforeProccessing[i]["adv"]["tradeMethods"].length - 1) {
        payTypesz += ", ";
      }
    }
    obj = {
      tradeType: tempDataBeforeProccessing[i]["adv"]["tradeType"],
      asset: tempDataBeforeProccessing[i]["adv"]["asset"],
      fiatUnit: tempDataBeforeProccessing[i]["adv"]["fiatUnit"],
      price: tempDataBeforeProccessing[i]["adv"]["price"],
      surplusAmount:
      tempDataBeforeProccessing[i]["adv"]["surplusAmount"],
      maxSingleTransAmount:
      tempDataBeforeProccessing[i]["adv"]["maxSingleTransAmount"],
      minSingleTransAmount:
      tempDataBeforeProccessing[i]["adv"]["minSingleTransAmount"],
      nickName:
      tempDataBeforeProccessing[i]["advertiser"]["nickName"],
      monthOrderCount:
      tempDataBeforeProccessing[i]["advertiser"]["monthOrderCount"],
      monthFinishRate:
      tempDataBeforeProccessing[i]["advertiser"]["monthFinishRate"],
      payTypes: payTypesz,
    };
    finalData.push(obj);
  }

  console.log(finalData);
};

const entireCall = async function() {
  await getTheData();
  processData();
};

exports.scheduledFunction = functions.pubsub
      .schedule("every 1 minutes")
      .onRun(async (context) => {
        await database.collection("SebiBinanceSale").doc("BCR Bank").delete();
        await entireCall();
        for (let i = 0; i < finalData.length; i++) {
          await database.collection("SebiBinanceSale").doc("BCR Bank")
              .collection("1").doc(i.toString())
              .set({
                "tradeType": finalData[i]["tradeType"],
                "asset": finalData[i]["asset"],
                "fiatUnit": finalData[i]["fiatUnit"],
                "price": finalData[i]["price"],
                "surplusAmount": finalData[i]["surplusAmount"],
                "maxSingleTransAmount": finalData[i]["maxSingleTransAmount"],
                "minSingleTransAmount": finalData[i]["minSingleTransAmount"],
                "nickName": finalData[i]["nickName"],
                "monthOrderCount": finalData[i]["monthOrderCount"],
                "monthFinishRate": finalData[i]["monthFinishRate"],
                "payTypes": finalData[i]["payTypes"],
              });
        }
        return console.log("Succes Upload of the data ");
      });
```

error:

```
Function failed on loading user code. This is likely due to a bug in the user code. Error message: Error: please examine your function logs to see the error cause: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/logging#viewing_logs. Additional troubleshooting documentation can be found at https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting#logging. Please visit https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting for in-depth troubleshooting documentation.

Functions deploy had errors with the following functions:
        scheduledFunction(us-central1)
i  functions: cleaning up build files...

Error: There was an error deploying functions
ivanoiualexandrupaul@Ivanoius-MacBook-Pro functions %
```

log file :

```
 [debug] [2022-10-29T17:40:16.776Z] Error: Failed to update function scheduledFunction in region us-central1
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/deploy/functions/release/fabricator.js:41:11
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
    at async Fabricator.updateV1Function (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/deploy/functions/release/fabricator.js:305:32)
    at async Fabricator.updateEndpoint (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/deploy/functions/release/fabricator.js:140:13)
    at async handle (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/deploy/functions/release/fabricator.js:78:17)
[error] 
[error] Error: There was an error deploying functions
```

Comment: Alex97, please let me know if the recommendations below were helpful.

Comment: Please update more details of what you tried and is it the same error that you got earlier.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using scheduled functions in Firebase Functions, an App Engine instance is created that is needed for Cloud Scheduler to work. You can read about it [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions).They use the location that has been set by default for resources. I think that you are getting this error because there is a difference between the default GCP resource location you specified and the region of your scheduled cloud function.Check your Cloud Scheduler function details and see which region it has been deployed to. By default, functions run in the us-central1 region. Check this [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#modify-region) to see how we can change the region of the function.

You can also try re installation using the command

```
npm install -g firebase-tools
```

Also check if any lock files are generated and delete these and run the firebase deploy --only functions again and see if that works.

Comment: I already tried that and it is not working